# Fancy Box 2 calling html page

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a simple application i am working on i have defined fancybox on the page i would like for the content of the page to load into the fancy box window. I got it working with calls to other pages by using href html tag. However i would like when the document loads that it opens in fancybox. Under is my code:

What i want to achieve is i want to have the fancybox settings defined on the page which will be shown in it. When the page loads or is called via other means that by the user i would like for it to be displayed in a fancybox.

**JScript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".fancybox").fancybox({

                autoDimensions : false,
                width: 1300,
                height: 'auto',
                openEffect  : 'elastic', 
                href        : 'http://hello.htm'
                    closeEffect : 'elastic',
                    type: 'iframe',

                beforeLoad: function() {
                    this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');

                }

            });         
        });
    </script>
```

This page is being called from another fancy box window however the fancybox window belongs to the old page since the title of the old page remains

**Jsp**

```
<head>
 <title>Simple Application</title> 

  </head>
  <body>
<form:form id="hello">
    <h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>
    <p><fmt:message key="greeting"/></p>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at the [Fancybox 2 docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs), I'm not seeing the `url` option. Perhaps remove it?

Comment: Ok, the `html` option "overrides content source link". This means if you leave it out, it will render the content of `.fancybox`. Is that what you want?

Comment: i am not sure i understand you but what i am trying to do is i have application when i enter the main menu i click on a link, an href and this opens a form in a fancybox window this works perfectly. I also included the 'title' option on the fancybox window. When the page is open the user can see a title under the page. When i post this page to the server i send the user to another page the fancybox window does not close it renders the new content in the old fancy box window. The title remains the same for the newly rendered html.

Comment: I am thinking the old fancybox window is suppose to be closed off when the submit is made and a new one opened for the page the user is redirected to and the title will also show the title of the page the user was redirected to. I am not sure how to accomplish. This is the major problem i am having